# Export MySQL to CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have below script to export MySQL data to csv file.This script export everything inside the while loop but I want to put constant value in a 2nd column or just want to keep 2nd column empty and put MySQL data in column 1 and column 3.

```
// output the column headings
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));

// fetch the data
$rows = mysql_query('SELECT field1,field2 FROM table');

// loop over the rows, outputting them
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

Comment: `(select 'Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3') union (SELECT field1,"", field2 FROM table) INTO OUTFILE 'filename'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have field1 (i.e-Column1) and field2(i.e-Column3)
so just add Null at 2nd position like below

```
$insert = array( '' );
array_splice( $row, 1, 0, $insert );
```

then use

```
fputcsv($output, $row);
```